# Cast anonymous two-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, casting, anonymous-arrays

Is it possible to create an anonymous array like this?

```
char **values = (*char[]){"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};
```

This method works:

```
char **values
char *tmp[] = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};
values = tmp;
```

Comment: If you do find a way to create such an array directly, you should probably terminate it with `NULL`, else there will be no way to find the end:  `char **values = (*char[]){"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", NULL};`

Comment: Re “`(*char[]){"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"}`”: Is that a typo; do you mean `(char *[]){"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"}`?

Comment: No, it isn't. I thought it was correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) (which creates an anonymous object whose address *can* be taken). You just need to get the *type* of that compound literal correct (in your case it will be `char*[]`), then take its address using the `&` operator:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // The outer brackets on the RHS are not necessary but added for clarity...
    char *(*values)[3] = &( (char* []) { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" } );
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) printf("%s\n", (*values)[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you could take advantage of the fact that an array (even one defined as a compound literal) will automatically 'decay' to a pointer to its first element (in most circumstances, including when used as the RHS of an assignment operation):

```c
int main()
{
    char** values = (char* []){ "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) printf("%s\n", values[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `char **`, except for the typo in the question (`*char` instead of `char *`). The compound literal `(char *[]) {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"}` is an array that will be automatically converted to `char **`.

Comment: @Eric Yes, indeed. After some fumbling and confusion-resolution, I have offered that as an alternative. ;-)